# A better (maintainable) way to show/hide html table columns and store column preferences in a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, birt

I work in a reporting platform that uses Spring, BIRT, jQuery and hibernate.

This tool can display many different reports to users, each report is displayed as an html table (which is created using a BIRT emitter).

A very important feature that we support is showing and hiding certain columns from the reports, the user can toggle each column and his preference is saved in a database. The way we accomplish this task is not optimal, it requires a lot of maintenance and often breaks.

For each report(there are many) we have a `.properties` file in which all columns of the report are listed. This property is read and with it we generate a dialogue listing all columns and check-boxes beside them, when the users select/deselects columns and hits "save", we create an arrays of 0s and 1s (e.g. 0011111111, here the first 2 columns are hidden and the last 8 are showing), pass this array to BIRT to generate a new HTML table with the corresponding columns shown or hidden and we also store this array of 0s and 1s as a user preference in our database.

Can anyone suggest a better approach to solving this problem ?

What I want is to not have to update all users preferences in the DB and the report `.properties` file every time we add/remove/update column(s) in a report (it has to be done because it would change the location of the 0s and 1s in the array).

Comment: What about one table with the reports, one with the available columns and one with a user-column mapping? That way if you add a column to a report, no changes in any other table are necessary; only if the user explicitly selects a previously unselected column would you have to store that information.

Comment: @DaDaDom: Sounds like a good answer to me - why not add it as an answer?

Comment: @Gihad: What DB are you using?

Comment: @MarkBannister: Thx for the idea, I tend to comment first as that usually helps if I got the question wrong. But sounds good, I'll add it.

Comment: @MarkBannister: For storing the user column preferences I'm using mysql

Answer (score 1):

What about one table with the reports, one with the available columns and one with a user-column mapping? That way if you add a column to a report, no changes in any other table are necessary; only if the user explicitly selects a previously unselected column would you have to store that information.

The tables would be connected like

```
reports 1<-->n columns 0..n<-->0..m users
```

Comment: I suppose that if I have 'reports 1<--->n Columns' in the DB, than I can read those values to know all the columns that a report supports, not needing to hardcode all column names in the .properties file that I currently use.

I might use this solution, I will get back to this page and post how I solved the problem.

Comment: That's exactly the point: Define the available columns per report in one table/relationship and the ones selected by the user in another. That way you can add new columns to reports without having to change the columns selected by the user.

Comment: The problem is that BIRT needs the '0011111111' type of array to know if it has to show or hide a column when it generates a report. Even if I add new tables to the database I will still have this problem, which is my main issue.

I need to get away from using this indexing method in BIRT, but I'm not sure how, sending column names to BIRT won't help.

Comment: Is there a way you can somehow send a "dynamic" array instead by just calculating the array for the user every time it is requested/required? I don't know BIRT, so I am not sure if this is possible. On the other it is quite easy to re-calculate the array every time something changes, either on report-structure side or on user-preferences side.

Comment: I'm looking into a way of attaching a unique id to each column in the BIRT report designer, if I have that I can than step away from the indexing method. I have to play around with the BIRT html emitter, seems like my question is a bit different now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON schema to represent the table configuration. Since it's not searchable, indexed or linked to anything else, just store it as a text blob in the database.